# Conditional styling using props in emotion/react is not working properly

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm trying to add conditional styling to PhoneInput component from 'react-phone-number-input' library with use of emotion react styling library. I want to add some css properties based on screen width.

This is how prop is passed, I see in console.log() that value on the screen width is updated:

```
const [windowWidth, setWindowWidth] = useState(window.innerWidth);

  const handleResize = () => {
    setWindowWidth(window.innerWidth);
  };
  console.log(windowWidth);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
    };
  }, [windowWidth]);

  return (
    <FormControl isInvalid={touched && errors}>
      <FormLabel>{label}</FormLabel>
      <StyledPhoneInput
        width={windowWidth}
        id={id}
        {...rest}
        defaultCountry="PL"
        value={values}
        onChange={onChange}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        international
        onBlur={onBlur}
      />
```

In StyledPhoneInput component I have it implemented like below, I made console.log() inside the component and I see that it's passed properly.
I want to add conditional styling to class .PhoneInput, I see in dev tools that it's working adding it to this class.

```
interface StyledTextInputProps {
  width: number;
}

export const StyledPhoneInput = styled(PhoneInput)<StyledTextInputProps>`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  border-bottom: 2px solid;
  border-color: ${colors.gray[200]};
  padding-bottom: 16px;

  ${(props) => {
    console.log('Width prop:', props.width);
    return '';
  }}

  .PhoneInput {
    align-items: ${(props) => props.width < 550 && 'flex-start'};
    flex-direction: ${(props) => props.width < 550 && 'column'};
    background-color: ${(props) => props.width < 550 && 'red'};
  }
```

Can You please let me know what is wrong and how to fix it ?

regards

Comment: In the StyledPhoneInput component, you are passing in the width but you are not adding the px or % to it. I'm not aware of the library you are using, but I just thought that the px is missing. Can you cross-check if you are passing the width correctly.

Comment: why not to use media queries?